# Paypal with Sandbox give me Invalid payer country Error

Tags: paypal, payum

I stuck on the Paypal recurring payment process.
I use the Payum Symfony Bundle to create the recurring request.
I use the Paypal Sandbox.

All looks fine, the Code redirect me to Paypal, i can login and acceppt the reccuring but the callback to my server give me a error: **Invalid payer country**

I pay with my **sandbox buyer user** , located in **Germany**

This is the error response

```
"L_ERRORCODE0" => "11543"
"L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Invalid payer country"
"L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "The payer's country is currently not supported."
"L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
```

and this is my Payum call:

```
    $recurringPayment['TOKEN'] = $agreement['TOKEN'];
    $recurringPayment['DESC'] = 'Test Subscribe for 0.05$ per day.';
    $recurringPayment['EMAIL'] = $agreement['EMAIL'];
    $recurringPayment['AMT'] = 0.05;
    $recurringPayment['CURRENCYCODE'] = 'EUR';
    $recurringPayment['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = 7;
    $recurringPayment['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = date(DATE_ATOM);
    $recurringPayment['BILLINGPERIOD'] = Api::BILLINGPERIOD_DAY;
```

Its the original Sample from [Payum](https://github.com/Payum/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/blob/master/Resources/docs/recurring-payments-basics.md)

When i try to set the shipping data, the same results comes up

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: this happend only when i use a GERMAN test account, the US test account works fine :/

Comment: ok its not possible... -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682410/express-checkout-for-recurring-payments-does-not-work-for-german-payers